# Express req.body is empty when using the http.post

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, post

I do not know why the req.body is EMPTY...
**app.js** use the body-parser middleware(http://www.expressjs.com.cn/4x/api.html#req.body)

```
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var index = require('./routes/index');
var users = require('./routes/users');
var app = express();
// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

// add baseurl
app.use('/api', index);
app.use('/api', users);
```

**user.js**

```
router.route('/user')
.post(function (req, res, next) {
    console.log(req.body);
    console.log(req.headers);
    //console.log(JSON.parse(Object.keys(req.body)[0]));
    res.json({title: 'RESTful: POST...'});
});
```

I have printed the headers: But the req.body is empty and I used the JSON.parse(Object.keys(req.body)[0]) to parse the result from the other similar question, but it did not work to me.
I use the postman to request the POST,

```
{ 'cache-control': 'no-cache',
'postman-token': 'db7766d7-767c-4d33-be3a-acfa18ac1d9c',
'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
'user-agent': 'PostmanRuntime/6.4.1',
accept: '*/*',
host: 'localhost:3000',
'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate',
'content-length': '0',
connection: 'keep-alive' }
```

[postman screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wN6Vd.png)

Comment: Why do you need `JSON.parse` at all? You are passing simple numbers and strings.

Comment: Do you achieve similar results--or rather, failure--posting a request with a JSON body?

Comment: @Joy check out.

Comment: @Maluen acutally, I just try to use it. but throw an error, and then I am commeted out it

Comment: @ Fissure King If I use the application/json and raw data is {"name": "user"}, I get the JSON data form req.body, but what is the reason why can't get it by x-www-form-urlencoded??

Answer (score 2):

Your routes seem to be configured correctly.  I'd rule out any funny business with postman by trying to make the same request using `curl`.

```
curl -d "@/path/to/payload.json" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST http://localhost:3000/api/user
```

What happens then?

**EDIT:** From what I gather in the comments, it looks like the request you were posting contained a `Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded` header, but with a JSON body `{"name":"user"}`.  In other words, **the content-type header and the body are mismatched**.

Because the server was expecting URL encoded content, it would have been unable to parse the request body.  For that reason, it's important to make the `Content-Type` header agree with body format.  So in this case, you have two options.

1. Keep `Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded` and change the body to `name=user`
2. Change your header accordingly to `Content-Type: application/json` and keep the body as `{"name":"user"}`

Comment: Hi An Camchéachta, if I change to application/json and the raw data is {
"name": "user"}, I can get the json data from req.body, but why  x-www-form-urlencoded can't ??

Comment: `{ 'cache-control': 'no-cache',
  'postman-token': '852df9bf-d4f2-481d-baab-f91b3354f16b',
  'content-type': 'application/json',
  'user-agent': 'PostmanRuntime/6.4.1',
  accept: '*/*',<br>
  host: 'localhost:3000',<br>
  'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate',
  'content-length': '19',
  connection: 'keep-alive' }
{"name":"user"}` <-- content of req.body

Comment: Hi Joy,
Sure.  Are you sending the body in question as a valid urlencoded string?  In other words, is the body getting sent as: `name=user`?  There's a great explanation for how to format your body as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` [in this Mozilla doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/POST).  Might you have been sending over a string of JSON instead of this?

Comment: Hi  An Camchéachta, at the footer of my question, there is a screenshot of the postman which includes the data sent by  application/x-www-form-urlencoded, I think the data format is right, as the data structure is provided by postman.

Comment: Hi @An Camchéachta **Keep Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded and change the body to name=user** this case is what I wanted, as the screenshot shown, but the result it is unexpected.

Comment: As I see from Google search results, postman lets you [inspect the raw body](https://www.getpostman.com/docs/postman/sending_api_requests/requests#raw).  Maybe that will help you.

Comment: `{ 'cache-control': 'no-cache',
 'postman-token': 'ab73ef15-3313-4cde-b687-85cf0397da0b',
 'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
  'user-agent': 'PostmanRuntime/6.4.1',
 accept: '*/*',
  host: 'localhost:3000',
  'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate',
  'content-length': '19',
 connection: 'keep-alive' }`
{"{\n\t\"name\": \"user\"\n}":""} //the req.body when I choose the **text**  raw data` in postman. But from the postman introduction: https://www.getpostman.com/docs/postman/sending_api_requests /requests, I can input form data as the screenshot.@An Camchéachta

Comment: CamchéachtaI created a view to test the post, it worked **{"user_name":"joy","age":"12","country":"China"}**. but I do not know why.<form action="api/user" method="post"></form>

Comment: created a view to test the post, it worked **{"user_name":"joy","age":"12","country":"China"}**. but I do not know why.<form action="api/user" method="post"></form>

Answer (score 0):

Try this package. It is useful when you are passing form data and not in json format.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/formidable

Comment: Hi @parth, maybe this package is a good way to get  form data not in json format. And I want to know why when I set the **Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded**, and the sent data format is right, but can't not receive the result by req.body? Could u help to explain it?

Comment: Explanation given on this link . https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4007969/application-x-www-form-urlencoded-or-multipart-form-data.
Also when sending other then json data, look your headers. If it's set to Applocation/json then uncheck it.